# Buffering packets vs. low latency routing

Tags: computer-networks, empirical-research, routing

I am considering strategies to compare the performance of routers with buffers vs. their lower latency counterparts in a simple network setting (N clients communicating with each other randomly through a router). I know that buffered routers should ideally perform better when there are traffic bursts.

My question is regarding my concern which is that I do not know what is a good strategy to pick scenarios and how could I convey that these models are relevant to common real world situations. So the question would be:

1. How to pick scenarios that are similar to real world situations?
2. How to convince that these scenarios are indeed relevant to real
   world situations.

My main concern is measuring the benefit of buffers vs. an improvement in RRT (lower latency) with varying levels of congestion. Also showing possible disadvantages where the amounts of congestion are overwhelming (buffer bloat) and possibly other patterns.

Comment: this sounds like [networkengineering.se] unless you are doing simulations ... are you working with real hardware and wanting to do hardware benchmarking?

Comment: So what is your question, exactly?  I don't see a question in here.  (If you are asking "What simulated workloads should I use?", the answer is going to depend heavily on what you are trying to accomplish, what deployment scenarios you are targeting, and other details -- I am not optimistic that we can give you a one-size-fits-all answer.)

Comment: I am working with ns3 and doing software simulations.
@D.W. I will try to modify the question to better pinpoint the area I would like to shed some light upon.